# How to count the number of queries executed in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, perl-module

I have 2 sql files and each containing 100 queries. 
I need to execute first 10 queries from the first sql file and then execute first 10 queries from 2nd sql file. After the executions of 10 queries from 2nd sql file, the 11th query should start execution from the 1st sql file.

Is there a way to keep count of how many queries have completed?
How to pause the query execution in 1st file and resume it after completion of certain number of queries?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why?

Comment: If each query is in a separate line, you can use shell to head n rows from one file, execute them, head m rows from second file, execute them etc? Here we are not pausing, we are just switching between the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the `psql` command line client, its include file handling is limited to reading the file and sending the whole contents to the server query-by-query.

You'll want to write a simple Perl or Python script, using `DBD::Pg` (Perl) or `psycopg2` (Python) that reads the input files and sends queries.

Splitting the input requires parsing the SQL, which requires a bit of care. You can't just split into queries on semicolons. You must handle quoted `"identifier"`s and `'literal'`s as well as `E'escape literals'`, and `$dollar$ quoting $dollar$`. You may be able to find existing code to help you with this, or use functionality from the database client driver to do it.

Alternately, if you can modify the input files to insert entries into them, you can potentially run them using multiple `psql` instances and use advisory locking as an interlock to cause them to wait for each other at set points. For details see [explicit locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html).